# HTTP file upload taking component for iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, httpserver

I noticed the functionality on some PDF viewer for iOS. You can actually turn phone in server and upload files there from a normal computer. I found HTTP server implementation from iOS on Google site, so implementing upload accepting functionality isn't a big deal for me. However I would like to save couple hours of my time, so if somebody could point me to ready to use solutions in sources, I will own you a bottle of your favorite beer.

Comment: I take payment in advance, please : )

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I will have an extra beer this weekend. No I didn't create one, but i found one
[enter link description here](http://deusty.blogspot.com/2008/12/http-server-iphone-example.html)

Actually I found bunch of them, but this one seems has upload handling code which was my goal. If somebody found a better server solution, then do not hesitate to share with me.